# the proper way to detect the current bar?

Tags: audiokit

I am working on a sequencer app based on the SequencerDemo app, using AKAppleSequencer.  It's been great so far, but now I need to add a new function to highlight the current bar.

Is there any delegate I can use to keep track of the bar that's currently being played?  What is the proper way to handle this?   Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using AKMIDICallbackInstrument as per suggestion by @c_booth.  And I added midi notes (2 beats per bar) to a separate (dedicated) track just to track the transport.

I put the following in init:

```
callbackInstr = AKMIDICallbackInstrument(
        midiInputName: "midiCallBack",
        callback: { status, noteNumber, velocity in
            let statusType = AKMIDIStatus(byte: status)?.type
            if(statusType == AKMIDIStatusType.noteOn){
                self.sequencerCallback()
            }
    })
```

and I'm tracking the sequencer.currentPosition.musicTimeStamp in sequencerCallback()

it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

`AKAppleSequencer` has the property `currentPosition` and `currentRelativePosition` which will tell you the position when queried.

You could include a sequencer track with one event at the start of each bar and send it to `AKMIDICallbackInstrument`.  You will have a callback function that will be triggered with these events. Here you can check the current bar and take care of highlighting it in the UI.